# SilverStripe, last guestbook entry in the sidebar or homepage

Tags: module, silverstripe

Does anyone knows how or point me in the direction to show the last guestbook entry (using the simple guestbook module) in the sidebar or homepage?

trying to have a go, I've put in HomePage.php this function

```
function LastGuest($nume=1) {
        $guest = DataObject::get_one("Guestbook");
        return ($guest) ? DataObject::get("GuestbookEntry", "", "Date DESC", "", $nume) : false;
}
```

and in HomePage.ss this:

```
<% control LastGuest %>
      <div class="newsList">
          <h2 class="newsTitle">$Title.XML</h2>
              <article class="newsSummary">$Comment</article>
      </div>
<% end_control %>
```

But it doesn't work. I get a 500 error. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turn on debug mode to see a detailed error report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. First see if you have a page of class `Guestbook`, grab the `ID` of the page. Then use that `ID` in the arguments to `GuestbookEntry::getEntryList`.

```
function LastGuest() {
    if ($guestbook = DataObject::get_one('GuestBook')) {
        $id = $guestbook->ID;
        $params = array(
            'filter' => 'IsActive = 1 AND IsSpam = 0 AND GuestbookID = ' . $id,
            'sort' => 'Created DESC',
            'limit_start' => 0,
            'limit_end' => 1,
            'comments' => false,
            'cryptmail' => false,
            'emoticons' => false,
        );
        $entries = GuestbookEntry::getEntryList($params);
        return $entries;
    }
    return;
}
```